# Create Primary Constraint from table columns

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a table named PRIMARY_CONSTRAINTS into the DB such as it has the table name, the constraint name and the column name of the primary constraints which I want to add.

It is an SQL oracle DB.

I have tried something like this but it does not run

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
      ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME PRIMARY KEY (COLUMN_NAME)
      WHERE TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME IN 
      ( SELECT TABLE_NAME,
               CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
               COLUMN_NAME
        FROM PRIMARY_CONSTRAINTS );
```

How can I reference it so I can alter the tables?
Thanks

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following dynamic block to achieve the same:

```
BEGIN
    FOR Q IN (
        SELECT
            'ALTER TABLE '
            || TABLE_NAME
            || ' ADD CONSTRAINT '
            || CONSTRAINT_NAME
            || ' PRIMARY KEY ( '
            || COLUMN_NAME
            || ')' QRY
        FROM
            PRIMARY_CONSTRAINTS
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Q.QRY;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I have created the small demo for you --> [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46896d5c5934a97434ccb8ced7bd24cb)

---

### UPDATED ACCORDING TO COMMENT

If there are two entries for a single table then You can use the following block:

```
BEGIN
    FOR Q IN (
        SELECT
            'ALTER TABLE '
            || TABLE_NAME
            || ' ADD CONSTRAINT '
            || MAX(CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            || ' PRIMARY KEY ( '
            || LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)
            || ')' QRY
        FROM
            PRIMARY_CONSTRAINTS
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Q.QRY;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo updated](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c98878f8785285dce9e3dace1474e0e)

Comment: Thank you really much, that is what I needed, it returns an error though, there are some constraints with 2 column name entries, can I solve it with a JOIN into the SELECT? or is it with a WHERE the correct sentence?

Comment: @Jorge : See the section "UPDATED ACCORDING TO COMMENT" in answer

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your comment about multiple columns on the constraints, we could setup the data in PRIMARY_CONSTRAINTS table in the same way it would be used in the Alter Table Statement.

For Example : Suppose we have to use the following statement to create a constraint  Alter table add constraint Constraint_Name primary key columnA, columnB;

Then the entry for this particular constraint in your PRIMARY_CONSTRAINTS table will have value columnA , columnB for COLUMN_NAME.

Hope this helps.

Regards
Akash